# The problem of gallery access and gallery opening not working in Android 13 (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, android-permissions, permission-denied

Why doesn't the gallery open when I click the button even when I throw a toast in the setonclicklisener code? What is the problem?
I have also placed an imageview so that when a photo is selected from the gallery, it will be placed in the imageview section, but I cannot access the gallery at all.

main_activity.kt:

```
package com.example.test

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var btn: Button
    lateinit var imageView:ImageView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        init()
    }
    fun init(){
        bindView()
        btn.setOnClickListener { checkAndOpenGallery() }
    }
    fun bindView(){
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn)
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
    }

    fun checkAndOpenGallery() {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            openGallery()
        } else {
            requestGalleryPermission.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        }
    }

    fun openGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        requestImageLoad.launch(intent)
    }


    private val requestGalleryPermission = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
            openGallery()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "permission de deind", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        }
    }

    private val requestImageLoad =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK && result.data != null) {
                val img = result.data?.data
                imageView.setImageURI(img)
            }
        }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="212dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,ImageContrastCheck"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="196dp"
        android:text="@string/open_gallery"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I wanted the gallery to open when I click the button but nothing

Comment: Do the logs show any warning/error?

Comment: No, no error was received Even in the debug section

Comment: What version of Android are you testing the app on?

Comment: test in android 13

Comment: This code has just been slightly changed and arranged. Please test again if you have tested it

Comment: It doesn't work on Android 13, but it works on lower Androids The problem was solved

Comment: What to do now for Android 13?

Comment: Yes, the reason can be understood from here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13. Was going to post the same. For Android 13+, you should use the new Photo Picker.

Answer (score 1):

> If your app targets Android 13 or higher and needs to access media
> files that other apps have created, you must request one or more of
> the following granular media permissions instead of the
> READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission: (contd.)

([Behaviour changes: Apps targeting Android 13 or higher](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13))

You should use the new [Photo picker](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker) which was introduced with Android 13 SDK (API 33).

Answer (score 1):

i find the problem and fix this code with ai:
this is the right code please use as this:
MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
private val PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1
private lateinit var imageView: ImageView
private lateinit var openGalleryButton: Button
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
    openGalleryButton = findViewById(R.id.openGalleryButton)

    openGalleryButton.setOnClickListener {
        openGallery()
    }
}
private fun openGallery() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST)
}
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        val imageUri = data.data
        val bitmap: Bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, imageUri)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }
}
```

manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/openGalleryButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Open Gallery"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/openGalleryButton"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```